# How to make a widget fill remaining space in a Column

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In Android, we can do the following to make `ImageView` to fill as much space as possible depending on the size of the `TextView`.

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How do we achieve this in `Flutter`? Assume I need to make `Datetime`(green) to fill as much as possible.

```dart
new Column(
    children: <Widget>[
        new Text('Title',
            style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
        ),
        new Text('Datetime',
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)
        ),
    ],
)
```

[image]

Comment: Don't you want the *image* to fill up, not the text? it's an entirely different subject making the font larger

Comment: I've edited the question. Please ignore the image, basically I just want to make the Datetime(the one in green) to fill as much height as possible depending on the size of Title. The font will not change.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Not 100% sure but I think you mean this. The Expanded widget expands to the space it can use. Althought I think it behaves a bit differently in a Row or Column.

```
new Column(
children: <Widget>[
    new Text('Title',
        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
    ),
    new Expanded(
        child: new Text('Datetime',
             style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)
        ),
    ),
],
)
```

Comment: Expanded will take remaining space in Row or Column.

Comment: Expanded takes area, But in release app, it shows the `RenderFlex` error, And All the widgets in expanded are can not be seen.

Comment: In my case `Expanded` were not working inside `Column`, because the `Column` itself were wrapped by `ListView`, hence removing unnecessary `ListView`, did the work.

Comment: Also if you are using an `Expanded` inside a `Column` which is inside another `Column`, please wrap the middle `Column` inside a `Flexible`, or it will take all the available space... None of the above solutions worked for me, took me hours to find this out.

Answer (score 32):

You can use:

1. `Expanded` with `Align` to position child

   ```
   Column(
     children: [
       FlutterLogo(),
       Expanded( // add this
         child: Align(
           alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
           child: FlutterLogo(),
         ),
       ),
     ],
   )
   ```
2. `Spacer`

   ```
   Column(
     children: [
       FlutterLogo(),
       Spacer(), // add this
       FlutterLogo(),
     ],
   )
   ```
3. `mainAxisAlignment`

   ```
   Column(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // add this
     children: [
       FlutterLogo(colors: Colors.orange),
       FlutterLogo(colors: Colors.blue),
     ],
   )
   ```

Answer (score 13):

If you need just to add blank space, use `Spacer()`

```
new Column(
children: <Widget>[
    new Text('Title',
        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
    ),
    new Text('Datetime',
        style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)
    ),
    Spacer(),
],
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Flexible(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
        new Text('Title',
            style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
        ),
        new Text('Datetime',
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)
        ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked in my case:

```
IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Image.memory(
                File('path').readAsBytesSync(),
                width: 150,
                height: 150,
              ),
              flex: 5,
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text('Title',
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                  ),
                  Text('Datetime',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              flex: 1,
            ),
          ]),
    ),
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be calling synchronous methods from within a `build` method. In this case, use `Image.file`.

Answer (score 1):

You must give a height to the `Row`, so its children knows the avaliable space. You can do it wrapping the `Row` with an `IntrinsicHeight` Widget;

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap the child of your Flex/Row/Column container that should be as small as possible in a **Flexible** widget and set it's fit property to FlexFit.loose and it's flex property to 0.
2. Wrap the child that should fill up the remaining space in an Expanded widget (this is the equivalent of wrapping it in a Flexible widget and set it's fit property to FlexFit.tight).

Applying this to your code, where 'Title' should only occupy the minimum necessary space and 'Datetime' should fill up the remaining space:

```
Column(
    children: [
        Flexible (
          fit: FlexFit.loose,
          flex: 0,
          child: Text ('Title', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text('Datetime', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
        ),
    ],
)
```