# Flutter put row into row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to create the following:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zziYr.png]

I could do it with code:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: 30
    ),
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text("label"),
        Container(
          width: screenSize.width - 30, // <- this is problem
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded( child: TextField() ),
              Expanded( child: TextField() ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

Is it possible to do it in a different way, namely the line `width: screenSize.width - 30`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use crossAxisAlignment inside Column widget and make it Stretch to get all remaining width in screen

```
Row(
children: <Widget>[
Container(
  width: 30
),
Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, // <- Add this
  children: <Widget>[
    Text("label"),
    Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded( child: TextField() ),
          Expanded( child: TextField() ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),],);
```

---

[Please read official flutter documentation of Column widget]

[Column Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html)

[CrossAxisAlignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CrossAxisAlignment-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      width: 50,
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("label"),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField()
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField()
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

### Explanation

It is about *where* you place `Expanded` instances.
You have a row, which can fill its parent if it included an `Expanded` child. So we defined the  size of one of its children (`Container`), and the other is simply `Expanded`. The same goes for the `Column` child ..

Maybe starting with a simpler example makes it easier to understand. Please refer to [this useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49978347/9714920).

### Output

[image: Resulted pic]

P.S. Welcome to StackOverFlow, Dmitry!